# Sub-query in a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  Patient No | Event Date | Exam Key | Event Key | Exam Code |
+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|           1 | 27/12/2015 |     4380 |      4792 | XHIPL     |
|           1 | 27/12/2015 |     4379 |      4792 | XPELV     |
|           2 | 11/02/2016 |     7006 |      2390 | XPELV     |
|           3 | 17/11/2015 |     5785 |      3948 | XHIPR     |
|           3 | 17/11/2015 |     5784 |      3948 | XPELV     |
|           4 | 13/03/2016 |     2633 |      7792 | XPELV     |
|           4 | 13/03/2016 |     2634 |      7792 | XHIPR     |
|           5 | 06/05/2016 |     6188 |      9169 | XHIPL     |
|           5 | 06/05/2016 |     6187 |      9169 | XPELV     |
|           6 | 05/09/2016 |     3396 |      3809 | XHIPR     |
|           6 | 05/09/2016 |     3397 |      3809 | XPELV     |
|           7 | 22/02/2016 |     8337 |      3706 | XPELV     |
|           7 | 22/02/2016 |     8336 |      3706 | XHIPL     |
|           8 | 27/11/2015 |     9376 |      7063 | XPELV     |
+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to display patients who had 'XPELV' and 'XHIPL' or 'XPELV' and 'XHIPR'

Comment: They are displayed. But seriously now, you should post your attempt at solving this.

Comment: so the output would be all patients expect 2 and 8? as they only have a single exam code and all the others have a one of the combinations?

Comment: Thanks Radu, just slipped from my mind to include my attempt...

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the results you need:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN TABLE TT ON T.[Patient No] = TT.[Patient No]
WHERE TT.[Exam Code] = 'XPELV'
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
               FROM TABLE T2 
               WHERE TT.[Patient No]=T2.[Patient No] 
                   AND (T2.[Exam Code] = 'XHIPL'
                       OR
                       T2.[Exam Code] = 'XHIPR')
               )
```

Comment: Hi Radu, it is just displaying patients with 'XPELV' exams. I wish it could display the other exams as well, so we could see all exams 'XPELV' and 'XHIPL' or 'XPELV' and 'XHIPR' a particular patient had.

Comment: @RomainHapi I've modified my query and I think it should give you what you want

Answer (score 1):

After a few tests, this seems to be the most efficient way:

```
select 
    t.PatientNo,
    t.EventDate,
    t.ExamKey,
    t.EventKey,
    t.ExamCode
from #Temp as [t]
where t.ExamCode in ('XHIPL', 'XHIPR')
    and t.PatientNo in (select t2.PatientNo from #Temp as [t2] where t2.ExamCode = 'XPELV')
```

I tried a couple of CTEs for you, and the above answer using EXISTS. This method is marginally (and I really mean marginally!) more efficient when comparing plans.

Comment: It all depends on the data that you have. I'm assuming that he only posted a part of the data. Also, we don't know for sure what indexes he has. Have you created any indexes on your temp table to test both queries? Also, what metrics did you use to compare the two plans? Query cost or something else? I don't want to disprove your answer, since it does give you the correct answer, but I'm not entirely convinced by the comparisons you used to pick the better option or to evaluate them both.

Comment: Simple test of query cost. Agreed indexing will play a part - I went purely on the information available.  I must stress the "marginal" part again - we're talking the tiniest difference.

Comment: Hi BishNaboB, it is just displaying patients with 'XHIPR' and 'XHIPL' exams. I wish it could display the other exams as well, so we could see all exams 'XPELV' and 'XHIPL' or 'XPELV' and 'XHIPR' a particular patient had.

Answer (score 1):

This query returns the desired output:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Patient
WHERE   [Patient No] IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                p.[Patient No]
        FROM    Patient p
                JOIN ( SELECT   *
                       FROM     Patient
                       WHERE    [Exam Code] = 'XPELV'
                     ) pp ON p.[Patient No] = pp.[Patient No]
        WHERE   p.[Exam Code] IN ( 'XHIPL', 'XHIPR' ) ) ;
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: Hi below is how the result would look likePatient No Event Date Exam Key Event Key Exam Code
1 27/12/2015 4380 4792 XHIPL
1 27/12/2015 4379 4792 XPELV
3 17/11/2015 5785 3948 XHIPR
3 17/11/2015 5784 3948 XPELV
4 13/03/2016 2633 7792 XPELV
4 13/03/2016 2634 7792 XHIPR
5 06/05/2016 6188 9169 XHIPL
5 06/05/2016 6187 9169 XPELV
6 05/09/2016 3396 3809 XHIPR
6 05/09/2016 3397 3809 XPELV
7 22/02/2016 8337 3706 XPELV
7 22/02/2016 8336 3706 XHIPL

Comment: Hi Yared, thanks for your input. It should return each patient twice as the exam_key is different for each exam. That's where I am stuck. Cheers